# How do I read values from columns of a .dat file in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

So I have a file full of data for six different things in a different column:

```
1   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4000
2   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4050
3   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4100
4   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4150
5   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4200
```

I want to read values from the six columns into this second file that I currently have set up below. I was intending to use these as input to be read into a third file, "inlist_changer.sh" file. I apologize, but I am not very experienced with shell scripting so perhaps in addition to this, you may know a more effective way for me to not even repeat the interchanging `bash` and `EOT` commands.

```
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value1
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value2
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value3
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value4
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value5
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value6
EOT
./mk
./rn
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value1
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value2
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value3
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value4
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value5
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value6
EOT
./rn
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value1
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value2
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value3
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value4
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value5
EOT
bash inlist_changer.sh<<EOT
placeholder_value6
EOT
./rn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell's `read` command to perform your operation without needing to modify an intermediate file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 ; do
  echo "v1:$v1 v2:$v2 v3$v3 v4:$v4 v5:$v5 v6:$v6"
  done < /path/to/data-file.dat
```

Check out the documentation for the `read` command by running `help read` from within a shell instance, and of course you can always get more documentation by running either `man builtins` or `man bash` or for your default shell `man sh`.